# why can't create user using stream chat api in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, stream, chat, getstream-chat

I'm trying to create a chat screen in my flutter application using `Stream chat API`. the problem is when I try to create a channel with two users it shows that the users are not created even though I have created them:

```
E/flutter ( 4695): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: 
StreamChatNetworkError(code: 4, message: GetOrCreateChannel failed with error: "The following 
users are involved in channel create operation, but don't exist: [hasan11 mohammed11]. Please 
create the user objects before setting up the channel.", statusCode: 400, data: 
ErrorResponse(code: 4, message: GetOrCreateChannel failed with error: "The following users are 
involved in channel create operation, but don't exist: [hasan11 mohammed11]. Please create the 
user objects before setting up the channel.", statusCode: 400, moreInfo: 
https://getstream.io/chat/docs/api_errors_response))
```

here is my dart code for initializing the channel and the users:

```
onPressed () {
  await streamAPI.initUser(client,
    username: 'hasan',
    id: Config.hasanID,
    token: Config.hasanToken);
  final channel = await streamAPI.createChannel(
    client, 'messaging', 'sample', [Config.hasanID, Config.mohammedID]);
  Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) =>
        chat(client: client, channel: channel)));
}
```

StreamAPI.dart code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:stream_chat_flutter/stream_chat_flutter.dart';

class streamAPI {
  static Future initUser(
    StreamChatClient client, {
      @required String username,
      @required String id,
      @required String token
    }) async {
      final user = User(
        id: id,
        extraData: {
          'name': username
        }
      );
      await client.connectUser(user, token);
  }

  static Future<Channel> createChannel(
    StreamChatClient client,
    @required String type,
    @required String id,
    List<String> idMembers
  ) async {
    final channel = client.channel(type, id: id, extraData: {
      'name': 'channel1',
      'members': idMembers
    });
    await channel.create();
    channel.watch();
    return channel;
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: you are calling await in the onpressed but where is the async?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that these users are created on the Stream backend. In your Stream dashboard, go to the **Explorer** -> **users** section, and you should see a list of all your users. Ensure the `IDs` match what you have in your code.

[Stream Dashboard Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwaYp.png)

Take note you don't need to call both `create` and `watch`, as `watch` will automatically create the channel.

If you're using the Stream Chat UI or Core components, you don't even need to call `watch` yourself, then you only need to call `create`.

I recommend taking a look at the Flutter tutorial page if you're still stuck: https://getstream.io/chat/flutter/tutorial/

Or the Stream Flutter YouTube Playlist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pO_MOJRqYlk&list=PLNBhvhkAJG6t-BxkRAnSqa67lm5C1mpKk